# Find coordinates of point in another coordinate system

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, translation

I've been wrestling with this very simple problem for a long time but I can't seem to understand how to go about it.

I have 2 coordinate systems. Each is different than the other in terms of point of origin, scale, rotation. I have to find the x,y,z coordinates of any random point on any of the coordinate systems on the other. Essentially a change of basis. The coordinate systems are built like so:

```
glm::mat4 matA = glm::mat4(); //Build matrix with identity
matA = matA*rotationA;     //Rotate
matA = matA*translationA;  //Translate


glm::mat4 matB = glm::mat4(); //Build matrix with identity
matB = matB*rotationB;     //Rotate
matB = matB*translationB;  //Translate

vec3 pointOnMatA = vec3( 5, 5, 5 );
//Find this point but on the matrixB coordinate system
vec3 pointOnMatB = ???
```

Comment: I think it is `pointOnMatB = matB*(inverseMatA*pointOnMatA);`.

Comment: @tsuki is the order of my rotate and translate correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as mathematics are concerned it should be

`pointOnMatB = matB*(inverseMatA*pointOnMatA);`

As for the question asked in the comment : I'm not familiar with glm, but matrix-vector multiplication requires that all components are of the same order (`mat4` and `vec4`).
If you're using openGL and homogeneous coordinate system, first three elements of the vector are X, Y, Z and the last component (W) should be 1. Here's a read for you:

http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/explaining-homogenous-coordinates-and-projective-geometry/

Answer (score 1):

The idea of converting coordinates of a point between different coordinate systems is first to find the transformation that aligns the coordinate frames and then apply the same transformation to the point. For example if we have two coordinate systems A and B, and we have a point whose coordinates are given in coordinate system A, find the transformation that aligns coordinate frame B to A, then apply the same transformation to the point and get the point's coordinates in coordinate system B.